# i would get choice in submenu

Tags: android

I would like to record in a variable the user's choice in a submenu, the problem is that the method onOptionsMenuClosed is never called.

```
   public class BrowserXActivity extends Activity {

       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       }

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    SubMenu subMenu2 = menu.addSubMenu("Scelta Lingua");
    //subMenu2.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_manage);
    subMenu2.add(2, Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, "Italiano");
    subMenu2.add(2, Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, "Inglese");
    subMenu2.setGroupCheckable(2, true, true);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if(item.isCheckable()){
        item.setChecked(false);
    }else{
            item.setChecked(true);
    }
    return true;
}

public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu){
    Log.i("A", "enter");

//  Log.i("A", "" + menu.getItem(0));
//  Log.i("A", "" + menu.getItem(1));

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `onOptionMenuClosed()`, just check what item gets selected in 
`public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` and remember it in a variable, that should work.